# Write to console in Gimp with Script-Fu

Tags: macos, gimp, python-fu

Unlike Neo I don't know python-fu. I'm also new to GIMP and am having trouble putting messages to the console:

```
def test(image, drawable):

  pdb.gimp_message("This is displayed as a message")
  pdb.gimp_progress_set_text("This message is displayed in the status bar")
```

I just get the message:

> ! Test Warning
>
> This is displayed as a message

Both commands takes strings so I 'm not sure if i've missed a trick somewhere.

Comment: You tagged `script-fu`, but you code appears to be in Python? script-fu is the other scripting language using in Gip (a Lisp/Scheme derivative...)

Answer (score 0):

If by console you mean a terminal, just use `print` (and start Gimp from  a terminal). If instead you mean the Gimp error message console, then `pdb.gimp_message()` is the way (if the console dialog/dock is used). You can force the console to be used (instead of a modal dialog) using `pdb.gimp_message_set_handler()`.

The output of `pdb.gimp_progress_set_text()` appears in two places:

1. over the progress bar at the bottom of the auto-generated dialog for parameter input (this progress bar is itself updated with `pdb.gimp_progress_update()`) if this dialog is used to start the script.

[image]

2. in the status bar of the image window (**while the script runs**) when there is no dialog (for instance, if you re-execute with Ctrl-F).

[image]

In both cases it is quite elusive if the scripts runs fast.